# how to use the switch in Netlogo to setup the pen either up or down?

Tags: netlogo

im new to netlogo i have a course work i did most of it , but i cant setup the pen to work with the switch what i should write as code to do this this is my code

```
turtles-own [pen ]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor sky ]
  setup-turtles

end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles turtles-to-create
  [ set color lime setxy random-xcor random-ycor set size size-of-turtle]  
  set-default-shape turtles "circle"
end



to go 

 ask turtles

   [ 
     fd 1
   ]


end

to goforever

 ask turtles
  [
    fd 1
  ]


end
```

Answer (score 5):

If your switch's variable is named `draw-paths?`, then you'd do:

```
to go 
 ask turtles [
     ifelse draw-paths? [ pen-down ] [ pen-up ]
     fd 1
   ]
end
```

By the way, you don't need both a `go` and `goforever` procedure. Just make a forever button that calls `go`.

Comment: thank you !! i have something else , i have a slider to edit the pen size how do i fit it onto the code the variable called turtle-pen-size

Comment: I see you've now asked this as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22286902/86485 (that's good, that's how things normally work on SO)