# How to setup a slider for pen size into the code in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

this is my code , i need to fit the slider so i edit the pen size my global variable is turtle-pen-size

```
 to setup
      clear-all
      ask patches [ set pcolor sky ]
      setup-turtles

    end

    to setup-turtles
      create-turtles turtles-to-create 
      [ set color lime setxy random-xcor random-ycor set size size-of-turtle]  
      set-default-shape turtles "circle"
    end

    to go 

     ask turtles[
         ifelse pen-down? [ pen-down ] [ pen-up ]
         fd 1
   ]

end
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt to solve it yourself? Where did you get stuck exactly? I don't see any code here having anything to do with pen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `pen-size` where you are asking each turtle to `pen-down`

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want to do in your code, the `pen-down?` is not defined in your code, I assume you have a turtle property which defines a pen-down? to one of values of true and false, if you define it a global value I believe all of your turtles end up with same value, for pen-size you can use following code

```
set pen-size turtle-pen-size
```

This is your completed code:

```
turtles-own[pen-down?]

    to setup
      clear-all
      reset-ticks
      ask patches [ set pcolor sky ]
      setup-turtles

    end

    to setup-turtles
      create-turtles turtles-to-create 
        [ 
          set color lime 
          setxy random-xcor random-ycor 
          set size size-of-turtle
          set pen-size turtle-pen-size
          set pen-down? one-of [true false]
        ]  
      set-default-shape turtles "circle"
    end

    to go 

      ask turtles[
        ifelse pen-down? 

          [ pen-down ] 
          [ pen-up ]


        fd 1
      ]
      tick
    end
```